# update_attributes rails differentiate between create and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, update-attributes

I have a nested form (very similar to the one shown in RailsCasts) that I use an update_attributes, which updates the parent object as well as updating and creating new child objects. I want to be able to differentiate between when a child object is created and when a child object is updated and when the parent object is updated. Is there anyway to do so? My immediate goal is to push a broadcast when a new child object is created.

Trying to use an after_create do in the child model doesn't work for my purpose because I'm trying to call an action in the application_controller.rb.

The code is my parent object controller is

```
if @parent_object.update_attributes(params[:parent_object])
  ...want the push_broadcast to go here if it's a new record.
```

If I use debugger, params[:parent_object] returns this

```
{"overall_sharing"=>"1", "permissions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"66"}, "1"=>  {"can_edit"=>"1", "can_copy"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"74"}, "1341967403169"=>{"user_id"=>"171", "can_edit"=>"1", "can_copy"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false", "note_id"=>"423"}}}
```

for reference, the last bit is the new child object, the first is updating the parent object and the middle is updating the child objects.

I don't know if the correct path is the try to mess with the params or to think of a different route. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Welles

Answer (score 0):

If it's a new record it won't have an id.  Unlike when editing or updating.

Just try to find it.  If you can't then it's new.

```
if params[:id]
  #existing record
else
  #new record
end
```

Comment: That makes sense but using the update_attributes method, how would I do so? My controller code for the update action is `@permission_set = PermissionSetting.find(params[:id])` at this point @permission_set only returns the existing permissions then `@permission_set.update_attributes(params[:permission_setting])` at which point @permission_set returns all of the permissions, including the new ones (which at this point have an id)

Answer (score 0):

Rails api has a [nice documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for nested attributes. (Rails guide falls short in this regard, in my opinion). I think it should answer most of your questions.